# Optimize performance for Datagridview in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, database, vb.net, datagridview

I'm developing system which is work with huge data (400k-500k records each time) using data grid view component (Load data from database - Insert, Edit, Delete in datagridview and store back to database) each table in database has many of fields (e.g., 77 fields).

I have problem with performance when doing it.
Each time click save button it takes a lot of time.

Any one has any ideal for this thing to perform it correctly.
Any ideal or suggest are appreciated.

Thank in advances

Comment: Use a backgroundworker to take the heavy proccesses ... is any of this data binary like images etc...

Comment: Golly why would you want to show up to _"500K"_ records to a user in a `DataGrid`?   In any event, use the **VirtualMode** of `DataGridView`.  [How to: Implement Virtual Mode in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b177d6d(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @436f6465786572 Though the `BackgroundWorker` is a fine idea, it perhaps does not address _"it takes a lot of time"_

Comment: Are you sure it's  not a database who slows everything down? Have you tried to execute your queries  directly? Are they fast enough?

Comment: Thank for your interesting and comment. That's is what my customer want, i'm maintaining the old system which they interact using files and i build a new system but unfortunately i cant remove some process (using file) coz of them want so. so now i have to figure out how to optimize performance of datagirdview process it's not about database, i'm talking about datababse coz i want to focus it's a huge data with huge fields in one records. And i want to focus into the perform of datagrid view when save back huge data which is loaded from database and just edit some record.

Comment: There are far too many unknowns here.  There is no way anyone can say why your code is slow without seeing the code or knowing some of the internals like the DB, data methods etc

Answer (score 0):

@James if I understand well your database users: insert, edit, delete;  *cells, or rows* from DGV using files ?
 so one single row of dgv is edited by a file.
 And Where is that DGV if your users edit in file ? 
Your DGV use BindingSources ? Entity Framework ,  SQL querys .. give me some details ..
check your string sql to database an see what you cam optimize, and show us what is in a new record saved sql string ..